# Web SpeechRecognition API- workaround for mobile devices not supporting continuous listening

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I'm trying to use the SpeechRecognition API to create a speech-to-text interface.
Here's my configuration:

```
const recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
recognition.continuous = true;
recognition.lang = 'en-US';
recognition.onresult = (event) => {...}
recognition.start();
```

It works great on desktop, but it seems that most mobile devices don't support **continuous listening**, and when trying to record from them the microphone turns on and off constantly.

I tried to work around it by immediately starting it again after the `onend` event:

```
recognition.onend= (event) => {recognition.start();}
```

But the problem is that `onend` fires **after** the microphone has been turned off, which makes constant beeping sounds on some devices, and problems fully recognizing the speech.

Is there any way to intervene **before** the microphone is turned off?